# Share website app files between servers

Tags: php, ubuntu, debian, haproxy

I want to load balance my website between many servers

think I have 5 server for processing user requests, one solution is to host website files on each server and use HAProxy to load balance requests

and another solution is to host website files in one server( NAS , SAN , DEDICATE SERVER ) and use servers to use that folder for website app

how can I achieve the secound solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need a connection (big and fast enough) to the storage server.
This could be FibreChannel, Ethernet and so on.

Mount the website files via multipathd, iSCSI, NFS, ceph, ... to the worker nodes.

Be carefully with concurrent writes, perhaps you need a clustered Filesystem.